# Regex pattern for quoted numbers and commas

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to find the correct regex to search a file for **double quoted numbers separated by a comma**.  For example I'm trying to find `"27,422,734"` and then replace it in a text editor to correct the comma to be every 4 numbers so the end result would be `"2742,2734"`

I've tried a few examples I found on SO but none are helping me with this scenario like

```
"[^"]+"

'\d+'
```

while the above do find matches, I don't know how to deal with the commas and how what to replace that with.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you in bash/shell? what tool are you using to replace the text?

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an even shorter solution (works with gnu-sed):

```
colonmv () {
  echo $@ | sed 's/,//g' | sed -r ':a;s/\B[0-9]{4}\>/,&/;ta'
}
```

But attention, the first sed command eats every comma, not just between digits, so improve it or filter your input before.

The second command uses the :a trick.

Read 4 digits, followed by a non digit (>) replace with the same plus comma, when a replacement took place, jump back from ta to :a and repeat.

Now, let's see colonmv in the wild:

```
colonmv '"A 3-grouped, pretty long number: 5,127,422,734 and an ungrouped one 5678905567789065778"'
"A 3-grouped pretty long number: 51,2742,2734 and an ungrouped one 567,8905,5677,8906,5778"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I finally got it :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be better way of doing but I propose the following approach:

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat to_transform.txt
abc "27,422,734" def"27,422,734" def
ltu "123,734" abc "345,678,123,734" vtu
xtz "345,678,123,734" vtu "345,678,123,734"
u "1" a
"123"
iu"abc"a "123,734"
```

**CMD:**

```
$ paste -d' ' <(grep -oP '(?<=")(:?\d+,\d+)+(?=")' to_transform.txt) <(grep -oP '(?<=")(:?\d+,\d+)+(?=")' to_transform.txt | sed -e 's/,//g;:loop s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\($\|,\)/\2,\1/g; s/,,/,/g; /\([0-9]\{5\}\)/b loop') | awk '{cmd="sed -i 0,/"$1"/s/" $1 "/" $2 "/ to_transform.txt"; system(cmd)}'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ cat to_transform.txt
abc "2742,2734" def"2742,2734" def
ltu "12,3734" abc "3456,7812,3734" vtu
xtz "3456,7812,3734" vtu "3456,7812,3734"
u "1" a
"123"
iu"abc"a "12,3734"
```

**CODE DETAILS AND EXPLANATIONS:**

- `<(grep -oP '(?<=")(:?\d+,\d+)+(?=")' to_transform.txt)` will extract each number to be processed from the input file, the regex used here use lookbehind/lookahead to enforce the surrounded by quotes condition, `(:?\d+,\d+)+` is used to extract the numbers like `27,422,734`.
- the `sed` command will getting the output from the grep command will then do the following operations:

**SED DETAILS:**

```
s/,//g #remove all , in the number
:loop  #create a label to loop
s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\($\|,\)/\2,\1/g #add a coma after every chain of 4 characters starting by the end of the string/or from the latest coma added
s/,,/,/g #remove duplicate comas added by the previous step if any
/\([0-9]\{5\}\)/b loop #if there are at least 5 digits present successively in the string loop and continue the processing.
```

**Temporary output** after the `paste` operation:

```
27,422,734 2742,2734
27,422,734 2742,2734
123,734 12,3734
345,678,123,734 3456,7812,3734
345,678,123,734 3456,7812,3734
345,678,123,734 3456,7812,3734
123,734 12,3734
```

Last but not least the `awk` command will read this file and run some sed command to replace every element of the first column by the corresponding value in the second command: `awk '{cmd="sed -i 0,/"$1"/s/" $1 "/" $2 "/ to_transform.txt"; system(cmd)}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Precondition: Your input conforms to "[0-9,]*" and is a "#,###"-format correct number.

```
#!/bin/bash
colonmv () {
     echo $1 | sed -r 's/,([0-9]{3})+/\1/g;' | \
     rev | sed -r 's/[^0-9]?([0-9]{4})/\1,/g;s/,"$/"/;s/.*/"&/' | rev
}

colonmv '"734"'
colonmv '"2,734"'
colonmv '"22,734"'
colonmv '"422,734"'
colonmv '"7,422,734"'
colonmv '"27,422,734"'
colonmv '"127,422,734"'
colonmv '"5,127,422,734"'
```

Test:

```
colonmv.sh  

"734""
"2734"
"2,2734"
"42,2734"
"742,2734"
"2742,2734"
"1,2742,2734"
"51,2742,2734"
```

Comment: @Allan: Is this ironic? :) I have to admit, that I'm not familar at all with the greedy-non-greedy prefixes. Might it be that they're pretty new? Sooner or later, I have to learn more about them. Sigh. :)

Comment: No no nothing ironic, look at my answer it is way too long!
In term of perf, I think yours is also nice! ( I have also to loop in the end within the `sed` code and I call many times `sed` and have `awk` to process a temporary file so...

Comment: @Allan: Found an even shorter one.

Comment: is `""` in `"734""` a typo?

Comment: You see things! No, tried it out, it's an artifact from the command. My new solution doesn't suffer from this bug. :)